# Sequential execution of IO from Future

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I have simple combinations of two IO with sending message to Telegram bot

`def send:Future[Message] = request(SendMessage(chatID, msg))`

How to combine IO in `greeting` to get output "second" after "first" every time.
I tried to use *>, flatMap, IO.fromFuture but the result was different.

```
first
second

second 
first
```

```
  def greeting(chatId: Long): IO[Unit] =
    IO(request(SendMessage(chatId, "first"))) *>
    IO(request(SendMessage(chatId, "second")))

  override def onMessage(message: Message) = message.text match {
    case Some(_) => greeting(message.chat.id)
      .unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works, it does not start the second `IO / Future` until the first one completes.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.effect.IO

def send(message: => String): Future[Unit] =
  Future {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    println(message)
  }

def greeting: IO[Unit] =
  for {
   _ <- IO.fromFuture(IO(send("First")))
   _ <- IO.fromFuture(IO(send("Second")))
  } yield ()

greeting.unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()
```